# Is there a way to update a VisualForce Page's Content Type through an IF-Condition?

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

Been looking for a way to update an apex:page content type but don't see any source about it AHAHA.
I have this ATM:

```
<apex:page standardController="sObject" extensions="<apexClass>"
</apex:page>
```

the apex class in the extension has a lot of functionalities and i have an href in the middle of the page that is linked to a template which when clicked can be viewed and saved as a CSV file.
but instead of viewing a template, I wanted to upgrade the functionality into a downloadable one. So i want to find a way to update the header that when the link gets clicked it adds this  `contenttype="application/vnd.ms-excel` to the header of the apex:page.

you guys have an idea if there's such a thing in VF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can put expressions in pretty much any Visualforce parameter including `apex:page`'s `contentType`. Something like this:

```
<apex:page lightningstylesheets="true" standardController="Contact" recordSetVar="contacts" extensions="SomeClass"
    showHeader="{!showForm}" sidebar="{!showForm}" applyHtmlTag="{!showForm}" standardStylesheets="{!showForm}"
    id="p" contentType="{!IF(showForm, 'text/html', 'application/vnd.ms-excel#Contactss.xls')}" readonly="true">

<apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!showForm}">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
            <apex:actionStatus id="status">
                <apex:facet name="stop">
                    <apex:outputPanel >
                        <apex:commandButton value="{!$Label.preview}" action="{!preview}" rerender="controls,preview" status="status"/>
                        <apex:commandButton value="{!$Label.export}" action="{!export}" status="status"/>
                        <apex:commandButton value="{!$Label.cancel}" action="{!cancel}" immediate="true" />
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:facet name="start">
                    <apex:outputPanel >
                        <apex:commandButton value="{!$Label.preview}" disabled="true"/>
                        <apex:commandButton value="{!$Label.export}" disabled="true"/>
                        <apex:commandButton value="{!$Label.cancel}" action="{!cancel}" immediate="true" />
                        <img id="status" src="/img/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." title="Loading..."/>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:facet>
            </apex:actionStatus>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="controls">
            put some form here, input fields...
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Preview" id="preview">
        optionally display first 10 rows or something
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:outputPanel>

<apex:outputPanel id="o" layout="none" rendered="{!!showForm}">
{!csv} Payload here
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

But be sure to check how it behaves in Lightning Experience (if you use it). Last time I played with it there was some extra output in LEX and eventually I cheated. I output CSV to hiddent html element, grab it with JavaScript.

```
<apex:commandButton value="{!$Label.export}" action="{!downloadCsv}" rerender="out" oncomplete="javascript:downloadComplete();return false;" status="status"/>

...

<apex:outputPanel id="out" style="display:none">
    <span class="payload">{!csvBody}</span>
    <script>
    function downloadComplete(){
        let payload = document.getElementsByClassName('payload')[0].innerText.replaceAll('<br/>', '\n');
        let filename =  'Equipment Utilization Report.csv';

        let link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(payload);
        link.target = '_self';
        link.download = filename;
        link.click();
        return false;
    }
    </script>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: OMG!! Thanks so much. This was what I was looking for and couldn't find in any docs AHAHHA. Thanks again! Bless u