# How do you fix the limitation of a contenttype in VF?

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

I have this VF Page with a contenttype that's supposed to shift dynamically. However I just found out in Salesforce's document that this is not supported in contenttype. Is there a way to fix this? or like a workaround?

This is what the code looks like:

```
<apex:page contentType = "{!IF(!showForm, 'text/html', 'text/csv#ABCD.csv')}" >
    <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!!showForm}">
        
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!showForm}">

    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

And the extracted file has an error with it which i suppose (??) is due to the contenttype not supporting the change that looks like this:

```
<span id="j_id0:j_id14"><script>if(window.SfdcApp && window.SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator) {
window.SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator.fireContainerEvent('force__vfRecordDataInvalidation', {}, true);
} else {
console.log('[VFRecordDataInvalidation] Not in Lightning, not firing invalidation');
}</script></span>
```

You guys have any idea for the workaround?

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72082410 I mentioned it might happen, "there was some extra output in LEX and eventually I cheated. I output CSV to hiddent html element, grab it with JavaScript". Have you tried the workaround?

Comment: oohhh i see now what you meant then. Gee HHAHAHAHA. I saw someone (from the web still) suggesting to revamp the code such that it doesn't make the page dynamically change from html to non-html. am still trying to wrap my head around that. I'll probably try calling another VFP at this point xD. thanks.